# Angular.js ng-repeat not updating the dom elements when i destroy the scope object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to delete elements in the ng-repeat from the controller for when a user scrolls down the screen to limit the amount of dom elements in view.

Heres what i have tried

```
$scope.someStuff = someobject..

delete $scope.friendsViewObject[SomeIndex];
```

And no success. If I delete the elements in the object alone the dom won't update.

And this is the directive that would call the controller.

```
<div myDirective="loadMyController()" ></div>
```

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (((raw.scrollHeight - raw.offsetHeight) - raw.scrollTop) < 10 ) {
                scope.$apply(attr.friendsWhenScrolled);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this inside a scroll event?  Can you show the context.

Comment: Hi, i've updated my post with mroe details

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$apply` on the attribute, when you change the DOM and you want angular to know about it, wrap the change in `$apply`.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        elm.bind('scroll', function() {

            if (((raw.scrollHeight - raw.offsetHeight) - raw.scrollTop) < 10 ) {

                scope.$apply(function() {

                   // delete here
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would i call the controller function? `attr.friendsWhenScrolled`

Answer (score 0):

OK i discovered the problem..

I think this might be an angular.js bug with the ng-repeat..

When i destroy elements in the scopes array the actual data is removed from view BUT the dom elements are still there.. It looks like the `ng-repeat` goes off `array.length` property without any pre checking.. so it gets all the array counting wrong.. So i had to use the method `shift()` to re-arrange all the elements..

Solution:

Change this

`delete $scope.friendsViewObject[SomeIndex];`

To This

`$scope.friendsViewObject.shift()`